# PhoneGap:WScript is not defined

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Currently I'm using phonegap 2.9.0.
And I got this uncaught reference error: WScript is not defined at file:///android_asset/www.cordova.js:18

I tried to search for other js file in the phonegap android folder to see whether I have missed out anything. But I couldn't find any other JS file for this WScript thing.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there is an example in phonegap folder.
And I have compared the two cordova.js, and is a totally different js file.
I copied the one from example to my app, and it doesn't throw any exception anymore.